# why are galaxies different in color?

Tags: star, galaxy, universe

whether its in movies,television,real-life or some planetarium different galaxies are shown in different color.

**For ex**:- Milky way is always seen in Blue where as Andromeda gives out a bit reddish color.

Is it because different galaxies contain different kinds of stars?
Does this effect the life the galaxy harbors...

^_^

Comment: Galaxies come in different colours because they are made of stars which come in different colours. Stars come in different colours because they don't all burn fuel the same way, depending on their mass, age, and content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [What do a galaxy's colors mean? Are they its true colors?](https://web.archive.org/web/20150117214502/http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/question.php?number=566) This article should help answer your question. There's really nothing I can add to the article. It lists all the reasons I could think of.

Comment: this article helped a lot :)

Comment: A warning from the last line of the article: "By the way, whenever you look at an astronomical image, you need to check that the colors represent visible colors. Often astronomers will take images in wavelengths that are not visible to the eye, and then use colors to represent various wavelength bands."

Comment: @Aaron brings up a good point. In research, I've come across a lot of different images of the same galaxy but in different colors, thanks to the different parts of the spectrum the photograph was taken in. Composite photographs can be even worse to decipher.

Comment: Bluegrass, could you please bring in more of the material from your link? Link rot has already made a user have to update the link to an archived version--we don't want to risk losing the information all together. Make sure to use quotes where necessary.